# require_once like for javascript ?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently searching a solution to not include two times the same .js

So my question is relatively simple, i'm searching something like requice_once (.php) or #ifndef(.c/.c++).

Are they solution for this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest that you use either [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) or [head.js](http://headjs.com/) for this kind of thing. They are fully-featured and provide performance benefits as well.

Answer (score 8):

You can write your own ifndef-code, just write your files like this (assuming it's for a browser):

```
if (!window.NAME_UNIQUE_FOR_THIS_FILE) {
  window.NAME_UNIQUE_FOR_THIS_FILE = true;

  .. your code here ...

}
```

The if-statement checks if the uniquely named variable exists already. If not, create it (so the next time this code is seen, it will be ignored). Then run whatever you want this file to do.

Be sure to use a **very** unique name though, since it's a global variable.

Comment: You mean that i have to put this at the top of my ".js" ?

Comment: I think he means to wrap your entire JS file in an IF block.  This appears to only work if you exclusively use function expressions.  This will not work with function definitions (see http://jsfiddle.net/XbAgt/ ).  You need to conditionally include the JS file as a whole.  A library like one mentioned in the other answers would probably be best.

Comment: XHR is correct. I also agree that a library for this would be a more genuine solution (if it's an option for you). Regarding function expressions vs function definitions, that would only be a problem in certain cases (where state is captured in the functions). If functions are overwritten by identical functions, it doesn't really hurt anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can include this file at the top of your HTML page.

include.js:

```
/* require.js */
if (typeof includedScripts === 'undefined')
{
    includedScripts = [];

    function isIncluded(name)
    {
        return includedScripts.includes(name);
    }

    function includeThis(name)
    {
        includedScripts.push(name);
    }
}
```

Then at the top of each subsequent included file, you can test and set, using this (e.g. for scripts/ajax.js here):

```
if (isIncluded("scripts/ajax")) exit;
includeThis("scripts/ajax");
```

This uses a global array, includedScripts, to track which scripts are included. This is a similar pattern to the very old C header file include test:

```
#ifndef __myFile
#define __myFile

/* content of your file here */

#endif
```