# Getting High charts error 16 when trying to load high charts for angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, charts, highcharts

component

```
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'cad',
    templateUrl: './cad.html'
})
export class cadcomponent {



}
```

cad.html

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="thumbnail alert-info alert alert-dismissible fade in">
                    <p class="lead text-center"> Our Dynamic KPI</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="scripts/cad.js"></script>

        <div id="container1" class="chart"></div>
```

cad.js

```
$.get('scripts/dataCAD.csv', function(csv) {
$('#container1').highcharts({
  chart: {
      type: 'column'
  },
  data: {
      csv: csv
  },
  title: {
      text: 'CAD'
  },
  yAxis: {
      title: {
          text: 'Units'
      }
  }
});

});
```

and my index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="icon" href="Resources/favicon.ico">
    <base href="/">

    <title>IT Status</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="center.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/highchartsdatamodule.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });</script>





    <script src="scripts/cad.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/market.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/system.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/speed.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/nickcodestatus.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/nickworkingon.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/seamuscodestatus.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/seamusworkingon.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/mikecodestatus.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/mikeworkingon.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/justincodestatus.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/justinworkingon.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/tonycodestatus.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/tonyworkingon.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/kevincodestatus.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/kevinworkingon.js"></script>
    <script data-main="scripts/main.js" src="scripts/require.js"></script>

  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->


  </body>
</html>
```

so i have googled the error and i am taken to this page http://www.highcharts.com/errors/16

I am just confused as to what i am doing wrong I do not see two calls to the high charts module. I have changed the container names to not all be the same as i saw in this post on stack overflow [Highcharts Error #16: charts not showing on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364172/highcharts-error-16-charts-not-showing-on-the-same-page) . If anyone could help me i would be very appreciative. I am almost done with the website this is my last problem that inst loading.

updated component

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({

        selector: 'cad',
        template: `
        <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="thumbnail alert-info alert alert-dismissible fade in">
                            <p class="lead text-center"> Our Dynamic KPI</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <pre id="csv" style="display:none">Month,Current,Previous
        JAN,100,100
        FEB,100,100
        MAR,100,100
        APR,100,100
        MAY,100,100
        JUN,100,100
        JUL,100,100
        AUG,100,100
        SEPT,100,100
        OCT,100,100
        NOV,,100
        DEC,,100</pre>
        <chart [options]="options"></chart>
        `
    })
    export class cadcomponent {
        constructor() {
            this.options = {
                chart: {
                    type: 'column',
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'CAD'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Uptime % for CAD'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEPT', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC']
                },
                series: [{
                    name: "Current",
                    data: [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,]
                },
                    {
                        name: "Previous",
                        data: [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,]
                    }]
            };
        }
        options: Object;
    }
```

Comment: I found that I am calling high charts in the following scripts                    <script src="scripts/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/highchartsdatamodule.js"></script>

Comment: I removed them and the page began to load but now i am getting the error highcharts is not a function! so closer we get to solving the problem!

Comment: Now that you have removed both of those scripts, your app cant find highcharts. What happens if you just use <script src="scripts/highcharts.js"></script>

Comment: i have got it working but i wanted to be able to read a csv file dynamically. that didnt work so i resorted to the structure above in the edit. still i would like to be able to read it from csv.

Comment: Could you recreate the problem in a live demo, e.g. in Plunker?