# Highcharts error 16 while setting global options

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to embed Highcharts into JSF and while setting the timezone offset, I get a javascript error that Highcharts is already defined (Highcharts error 16).

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="highcharts.js" />
<h:outputScript library="js" name="highchartsExporting.js" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { 
        Highcharts.setOptions({   
           global : {
              seUTC : true,
              timezoneOffset: #{cc.attrs.timezoneOffset}
           }
        });  ...........
```

But Highcharts provides this only as a global level setting so I can't set the `timezoneOffset` to my highcharts instance. 
Is there a way to set the global object without calling `Highcharts.setOptions()` ?

Comment: `yourHighchartsInstance.options.`

Comment: `Highcharts.getOptions().`

Comment: [stackoverflow similar solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17364257/3898339) go through it

Comment: Error #16 occurs when you try to load Highcharts second time on the same page. Are you sure that you import the script only once?